# How to render a child component within parent component using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to conditionally render a child component within parent component using react and typescript.

below is my code,

```
const Parent = ({ prop1, prop2 }: { prop1: Prop1, prop2: Prop2;}) => {
    const isChecked = true;
    return (
        {isChecked && <ChildComponent />}
        <SomeotherComponent>
            //some jsx
        </SomeOtherComponent>
    );
 }

 const ChildComponent = () => {
     return (
         <>
             <div>something</div>
             <div>something</div>
         </>
     );
 }
```

the above code gives me error like below

Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

could someone help me fix this. thanks. i am new to using react and typescript.

Comment: both your `parent` and `child ` components are in a same file?

Comment: child is in different file

Comment: if the answer was helpful try to give an upVote to it :)

Comment: @TaghiKhavari: could please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818598/how-to-multiselect-values-from-select-menu-using-react-select-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return statement of a react component only accept one jsx so you need to wrap your components

```
return (
  <>
    {isChecked && <ChildComponent />}
    <SomeotherComponent>//some jsx</SomeOtherComponent>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const Parent = ({ prop1, prop2 }: { prop1: Prop1, prop2: Prop2;}) => {
  const isChecked = true;
  return (
    <>
      {isChecked && <ChildComponent />}
      <SomeotherComponent>
      //some jsx
      </SomeOtherComponent>
    </>
  );
}
```